# this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key mapview

Tags: ios

I created application for MKMapView in iOS application to display map in my iPhone.
while running i got this

Error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<ViewController 0x9847150> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key mapview.'
***
```

can any one help me to solve this problem?
thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [This class is not key value coding-compliant for the key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088059/this-class-is-not-key-value-coding-compliant-for-the-key)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most probably you might have created an outlet called `mapview` and deleted it later. Check whether the outlets of MapView is broken in Xib/Storyboard.

Comment: yes thank you.i changed the mapView name so it cant be run, now i delete the IB and added again it works fine